# How to remove extra column created by aggregate function?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to remove a single column but I am not able.

For a context, I am trying to calculate certain summary statistics using data in the following format:

```
  State Year G1.Institutions
Alabama-1935 Alabama 1935              NA
Alabama-1936 Alabama 1936       0.4830918
Alabama-1937 Alabama 1937       0.0000000
Alabama-1938 Alabama 1938       0.0000000
Alabama-1939 Alabama 1939       0.4807692
Alabama-1940 Alabama 1940       0.0000000
```

From the data above I construct new table using:

```
descriptives<-aggregate(G1.Institutions~ State, grow_us, mean)
descriptives$sd<-aggregate(G1.Institutions ~ State, grow_us, sd)
y1935 <-panel_data[panel_data$Year %in% c(1935  ), ] 
y2019 <-panel_data[panel_data$Year %in% c(2019  ), ] 
descriptives$y1935<-y1935$Institutions
descriptives$y2019<-y2019$Institutions
descriptives$change<-descriptives$y2019-descriptives$y1935  
descriptives
```

which then gives me the following output:

```
   State G1.Institutions   sd.State sd.G1.Institutions y1935 y2019 change
1    Alabama      -0.7513443    Alabama           2.868676   207   106   -101
2     Alaska       1.5304305     Alaska          11.986212     2     4      2
3    Arizona       0.6237702    Arizona          11.817228    15    14     -1
4   Arkansas      -1.0421333   Arkansas           2.492121   213    86   -127
5 California      -0.4250102 California           7.484268   245   137   -108
6   Colorado      -0.7262110   Colorado           5.486192   141    67    -74
```

The problem here is that the aggregate function creates column sd.State which is superfluous and I would like to get rid of it. And this is where the trouble begins, this should normally be easy operation but it is not. I tried to remove the column using:

```
descriptives = subset(descriptives, select = -c(3) )
```

This got rid of the column 3 but interestingly it took the column 4 with it as well as now the data look like this:

```
                  State G1.Institutions y1935 y2019 change
1               Alabama      -0.7513443   207   106   -101
2                Alaska       1.5304305     2     4      2
3               Arizona       0.6237702    15    14     -1
4              Arkansas      -1.0421333   213    86   -127
```

I tried also some other common methods of removing columns such as:

```
descriptives = descriptives[,!(names(descriptives) %in% 'sd.State')]
```

Interestingly the code runs without error but has no effect:

```
                  State G1.Institutions             sd.State sd.G1.Institutions y1935 y2019 change
1               Alabama      -0.7513443              Alabama           2.868676   207   106   -101
2                Alaska       1.5304305               Alaska          11.986212     2     4      2
3               Arizona       0.6237702              Arizona          11.817228    15    14     -1
4              Arkansas      -1.0421333             Arkansas           2.492121   213    86   -127
```

I further tried:

```
descriptives$sd.State <- NULL
```

but for some reason that set the whole dataframe to null instead of just that one column.

No matter what I try I am unable to remove just sd.State column without removing also sd.G1.Institutions column. They seem to be somehow tied together. I think this has to have something to do with the aggregate function since I encountered this problem only when I am using it.

I tried to search past answers for a possible solution, but I do not even know what the problem here is. Answers to questions on removing column simply do not work here for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using $ notation to think adding a column as variable but instead you are adding an entire data.frame, If you do a str(your_dataframe). You will observe that the sd columns you have added are not just numeric column , it will show you as a list/data.frame. That is why you are having trouble in removing/changing them. A good way to start is not to do that. So this should work for you. Note, here both mean and sd are calculated in same step, you don't have to run multiple times descriptives to caculate sd and mean. Also there is call to `do.call` end the end to flatten the matrix structure of column at the very end. Note all this hassle can be easily solved if you choose to use `dplyr` or `data.table` operations.

```
descriptives<-do.call('data.frame', aggregate(G1.Institutions ~ State, df,function(x)c('mean'= mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), 'sd' = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE))))
```

The below is what the `str` looks like for descriptives now:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ State               : chr "Alabama"
 $ G1.Institutions.mean: num 0.193
 $ G1.Institutions.sd  : num 0.264
```

The below is what you are receiving at your end, you can see the difference in `str` outputs

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ State          : chr "Alabama"
 $ G1.Institutions: num 0.193
 $ sd             :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables: ## this is not right
  ..$ State          : chr "Alabama"
  ..$ G1.Institutions: num 0.264
```